# Green's theorem and intersection of plane with sphere

Tags: surface-integrals, greens-theorem, stokes-theorem

Evaluate $$\int _{C}ydx+\left ( 2x-z \right )dy+\left ( z-x \right )dz$$ where C is the intersection of the sphere$$ x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=4$$ and the plane $$z=1$$

Here's what I have thus far.

The intersection of the plane with the sphere produces $$x^{2}+y^{2}-3=0$$

Note that $$r\in[0,\sqrt{3}]$$

Observe that $M=y$ , $N=(2x-z)$ and $P=(z-x)$

How should I go further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intersection produces $x^2+y^2=3$ which is a circle on a plane $z=1$ with center at origin and radius $\sqrt{3}$ unit.

So applying Green's Theorem on a plane, and using
$z=1 \Rightarrow z=$ constant $\Rightarrow dz = 0$ 
$$\oint_C ydx+(2x-z)dy+(z-x)dz$$
$$=\oint_C ydx+(2x-1)dy+(1-x)\cdot 0$$
$$=\oint_C ydx+(2x-1)dy$$
$$=\iint\left(\frac{\partial (2x-1)}{\partial x }-\frac{\partial y}{\partial y }\right) dx dy$$
$$=\iint (2-1) dx dy$$
$$=\iint dx dy$$
Using polar co-ordinates, we have
$$=\int \int dr r d\theta$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}} r dr \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\theta$$
$$=\frac{3}{2}\cdot 2\pi$$
$$=3\pi$$